# Sharepoint 2013 - replacing links in Picture Slideshow

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, script, scriptlink

I'm using SP2013. The links in the OOTB Picture slideshow link directly to the image. I need to change the array that is default with some sort of script (which I'm not great with).
I did find this [solution](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/13395/how-to-set-link-on-images-with-sp-ootb-picture-library-slide-show-web-part) which is close but only addresses a single link not an array. 
Is anyone able to guide me in rewriting this script which will override the array. (I am not savvy with script).

Comment: This is an urgent request - is anyone able to assist?

Comment: Where do you want each image to link to?

Comment: I need the links to go to various places...external websites...document libraries...internal web pages

Comment: @garvon-77, did you find the solution for this?

Comment: Sorry for the delayed response - I did not get an OOTB solution. I have used a jquery responsive slider.